# efcore mapping to sqllite issue

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

i am developing a samll webapp with aspnetcore and efcore, created the project use the vs2017 defualt tempalte and replace with the efsql to efsqlite.

after create the table, i found that all datetime? are mapping to TEXT and not null.

```c#

```
// both are mapped with TEXT
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[StringLength(100)]
public string basename { get; set; }
public DateTime? requirementdate { get; set; }
```

```

ps: just use the annotation(code first), most of the columns are mapped to TEXT type. below is the generated table example:

[image]

Comment: See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Comment: Thanks, i will take a look right now